# An error occurred while installing net-ssh (3.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, nginx, capistrano

I want to deploy my rails app to AWS using capistrano and I followed a tutorial exactly as it is.

Here's the tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/

However, my domain is always showing 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu).

In fact, each time i run 'cap production deploy', I get this error:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@(my ip add): bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing net-ssh (3.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install net-ssh -v '3.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing net-ssh (3.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install net-ssh -v '3.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@52.25.50.168: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing net-ssh (3.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install net-ssh -v '3.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

I'm sure the net-ssh gem installation had succeeded (on both local and server side) so i dont know what is causing the issue here, hope someone here can help me.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

What I've tried: sudo apt-get install ruby-net-ssh

my ubuntu server gem list:

deploy user's:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler (1.8.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
jruby-pageant (1.1.1)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
net-ssh (3.0.2)
pg (0.17.1)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

default server's:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
jruby-pageant (1.1.1)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
net-ssh (3.0.2)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
```

And I'm still getting the exact same error as per above from running cap production deploy.

Someone save me :(

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue this morning, not sure our solutions are the same but here is how I fixed it.

I am running Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04) which got me Ruby 1.9.3 when installing the Ruby package.

First I encountered the error `net-ssh requires Ruby version >= 2.0` so I installed Ruby 2.2 from another source and then bundler.

Kept getting the same error as you even though I manually installed net-ssh 3.0.2 manually just fine.

Turns out bundler was still referencing some Ruby 1.9.1 library paths which was causing the problem.

To fix it I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby ruby1.9.1 bundler
sudo apt-get autoremove # to clean up removed Ruby packages
sudo gem install bundler
```

Then I was able to run `bundler install` and got no errors.

Hope that helps.

Comment: didn't work for me, i had given up and decide to use elastic beanstalk, but thanks! i'll definitely try again when I'm free.